# Get file contents using .env variable Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, variables, environment, lumen

Ok, so I have a .env variable CSV_FILE=~/sites/computer-availability/storage/app/WAV_SUM.csv

I want to load it into my controller so that I can parse it into an array. I tried env("app.CSV_FILE"); but that just gives me a string of the file path. Not what I'm wanting. I need the files contents.

How could I go about loading the data from the CSV file using the .env variable?

I have tried the following

```
$csv_data = Storage::get(env("WAV_SUM.csv");

$csv_data = env("app.CSV_FILE");

$csv_data = config("app.CSV_FILE");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official php documentation and slightly altered

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$csv = getenv('app.CSV_FILE');
$csv = str_replace("~/sites/computer-availability/","",$csv);
if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty    That's what I got when trying fopen()

Comment: @ZachTackett Could you try again ? i altered a bit the code for reading your environment variable.

Comment: fopen(~/sites/computer-availability/storage/app/WAV_SUM.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Good  progress - so where is your file located ?  what is the real path ?

Comment: ~/sites/computer-availability/storage/app/

Comment: and what is your current working directory ? Give me an example if you can like this :
Csv is in c:\myfiles\sites/computer-avaliability\strorage\app\
My website files are in c:\websites\myproject\

Comment: the file is located within the app directory. the full path is above in my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142839/discussion-between-simos-fasouliotis-and-zach-tackett).

Comment: I'm working from within the computer-availability directory. Also I'm on a Linux machine

Comment: That is returning a boolean value instead of the contents of the csv file